# DOTS Task Generates error on load

Tags: xpages

I'm running Domino 9.0.1 and was attempting to load up the DOTS task. Getting an exception when attempting to load it.  From the below it seems DOTS isn't installed.  Thought it was part of the default installation for XWork/ Domino 9x releases.  Do I need to follow the install steps for 8.5.3, another installer to use?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGiProfile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGiProfile
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:672)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
Unable to access OSGiProfile class, make sure the launcher.jar is in osgi-dots directory
```

thanks

-Mark

Comment: AFAIK Dots get only installed when you install the Social Extensions

Comment: @stwissel That's correct, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: thank you.  please do post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOTS extension started its life as an [OpeNTF project](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OSGI%20Tasklet%20Service%20for%20IBM%20Lotus%20Domino) by the ingenious [David Taieb](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/david-taieb/2/52/514), because he could and was later adopted for use with the OpenSocial Extensions (the part that renders the Embedded Experiences). So you need to have one of the two installed to get it to work. On a 9.0x server the social extensions are most current DOTS.