# Need help for OSGI Tasklet (java based) for Domino 9.0.1

Tags: osgi, lotus-domino

I was trying to integrate OSGI Tasklet with domino 9.0.1(java based). Unfortunately there was no latest bundle for java. I downloaded osgi tasklet service 2.0.3 zip and tried with domino. After the domino side changes done as per the document. i tried to load the plugin from the domino. End up with an error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access the core eclipse plugins directory
    at com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGILauncher.getPluginPathFromDir(OSGILauncher.java:229)
    at com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGILauncher.getPluginURL(OSGILauncher.java:200)
    at com.ibm.dots.launcher.OSGILauncher.launchOSGIFramework(OSGILauncher.java:136)

Google says its problem with the version of jars in domino and the OSGI tasklet service.

Does anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I have not tried DOTS, but version 2.0.3 is four years old and was intended to be used with Domino 8.5.3.  I don't recommend combining DOTS 2.0.3 and Domino 9.0.1.

Instead, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27362488/1192402) from @stwissel.  He recommends installing the OpenSocial Extensions to get DOTS working on 9.0.1.